# Can you do a sub select within a Case statement

Tags: t-sql, case

Probably something really trivial but I haven't quite found the answer I am looking for on the internet and I get syntax errors with this.  What I want/need to do is to provide a special case in my where clause where the doctype is 1.  If it is, then it needs to match the claimID from a sub select of a temp table.  If the doctype is not a 1 then we just need to continue on and ignore the select.

```
AND 
            CASE 
                WHEN @DocType = 1 THEN (c.ClaimID IN (SELECT TNE.ClaimID FROM TNE)
            END
```

I have seen some for if statements but I didn't seem to get that to work and haven't found anything online as of yet that shows a case statement doing what I would like.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a case statement, you could do:

```
AND (@DocType <> 1 or c.ClaimID in (SELECT TNE.ClaimID FROM TNE))
```

Answer (score 3):

A [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) *expression* (not *statement*) returns a single value. SQL Server supports the [bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603) data type. (Valid values are 0, 1, 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'.)  There is a [boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one. Your `CASE` expression attempts to return a boolean, give or take the unmatched parenthesis, which is not supported in this context.

You could use something like this, though Luc's answer is more applicable to the stated problem:

```
and
  case
    when @DocType = 1 and c.ClaimId in ( select TNE.ClaimId from TNE ) then 1
    when @DocType = 2 and ... then 1
    ...
    else 0
    end = 1
```

Note that the `CASE` returns a value which you must then compare (`= 1`).